# Best practice for numeric list within a card on mobile

Tags: gui-design, mobile, ios, lists

I have an iOS app that is to display bus times for different stops that the user has saved. Each stop will be a card in the view, and then in the card it's supposed to show the latest buses and when they're due. This is what I've got so far:

[image]

I'm happy with the card itself, I just don't know the best way to show the lists. There's not exactly a huge variety of data to work with to make it interesting.

All advice welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm missing some critical information here; where is the stop located and how long does each bus take to get to my destination? Not every bus takes the same route so arrival times will differ. Users may want to wait for the next bus if it means not having to go through a whole sight seeing tour of their town ;)

You can also add a few options to tweak these routes. Since the chance is very high the user will follow the same route in reverse, you can add a button that does exactly that; reverse the order. This will have the benefit of not cluttering your screen. You can also add a button here that lets you add notifications if there are delays and such.

To keep things clear, it might be better to keep each card full width so you can communicate this additional information. You can also opt to add a button to add new routes below the last card. Especially when a person hasn't added anything yet, a button like this helps users start the process for the first time if you couple it with some enticing copy.

[image: mockup]

Comment: All great advice! The thing is, the destination isn't known so time to the destination couldn't be used and because of this reversing it also can't be used.

Comment: What do you mean? How do you save a stop then if you don't know where you're boarding and where you're leaving?

Comment: The app knows where the stop is, but it doesn't know the user's end destination

Comment: But does the user know? Is it taking the stop nearest to you as a starting point by default?